# I installed freeradius using apt-get install, why it cannot find libssl when building the source?

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius, freeradius2

I installed freeradius 2.1.12 to my ubuntu machine:

```
apt-get install freeradius
```

Then I downloaded its source,

```
apt-get source freeradius
```

build the source:

```
cd freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg
./configure --prefix=/root/freeradius/freeradius-2.1.12
make
```

make fails:

```
        /root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/libfreeradius-radius.la -lnsl -lresolv  -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto
gcc -shared  .libs/eapcommon.o .libs/eapcrypto.o .libs/eapsimlib.o .libs/fips186prf.o  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/.libs -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/root/freeradius/freeradius-2.1.12/lib /root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/.libs/libfreeradius-radius.so -lnsl -lresolv -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfreeradius-eap-2.1.12.so -o .libs/libfreeradius-eap-2.1.12.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I wonder how come "apt-get install" can work, so I checked:

```
#type freeradius
freeradius is hashed (/usr/sbin/freeradius)

# ldd /usr/sbin/freeradius
        libfreeradius-radius-2.1.12.so => /usr/lib/freeradius/libfreeradius-radius-2.1.12.so (0x00007f3d6d1df000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f3d6c735000)
```

So libcrypto and libssl both exist at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Then how can I instruct configure to take /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

Comment: why are you installing both the binary build AND then build it from source?

Answer (score 0):

When building from source, you must install the development packages. These are usually named `<package-name>-dev` (Debian) or `<package-name>-devel` (RPM). Although, these should be listed in the `Build-Depends` entry.

On Ubuntu, this should be the package `libssl-dev`, which also provides header files.

---

Looking at [BuildingTutorial - Get the build dependencies](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial#Get_the_build_dependencies)

```
apt-get build-dep freeradius
```

should fetch the dependencies, and then

```
debuild -b -uc -us
```

builds the `freeradius` package.